# Handling authentication in a REST web application

Tags: angularjs, rest, authentication

I am using Angular JS as my front end framework and a REST server in back end (Using Spring). My Question is about handling the authentication in such a scenario.

So I have a login screen with email, password and a remember me option.
If I check remember me I am storing the username and password in a cookie.

While the page is loaded, if I find remember me cookie, I will login automatically with the details and obtain an auth token and use for the entire session. If I dont have remember me option, I will ask the user to enter username and password to login.

My issue is, If I use a different tab to open a protected page, if I haven't selected remember me option it is asking for login again. But I dont want that behavior. I want to persist the session info for all tabs.

How can I do that?

Comment: Hi. This question is still open, could you manage to find an easy / good looking way to implement this ? :D

Comment: I ma sorry, I couldn't find a solution. I was also searching for a good solution. Currently I am planning to use server sessions until I get a solution.

Answer (score 1):

First, I thing you should not store password in a cookie but instead the token you get from auth. This is safer because you can easily revoke a token when it is complexe to revoke a password.

You should give a look at [HTML5 localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage) which seems to do exactly what you need. The only concert is about the fact it will persist even if you close it (like a cookie). Maybe make sure it is deleted when you close the application (using javascript unload)

To make sure you remove localStorage on unload, you should keep track of how many tabs are open, and then only remove the auth on unload of the last tab :). It not last tab, you just decrease your localStorage counter of tabs ... should work, but far from being elegant.

Instead of coding it by yourself, you should use [intercom.js](https://github.com/diy/intercom.js/) which also go a little bit deeper :D

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I tested HTML5 sessionStorage. But it is not persisting for multiple tabs. I am using Chrome browser. Thanks for the safety tip.

Comment: What I did: sessionStorage.setItem("a", "b") from one tab, sessionStorage.getItem("a") from another tab. I used the same domain for both tabs.

Comment: Wow sh*t I was sure about it, just tried and actually yeah doesn't work ... sorry for that ... Mmh I will give a look on it more closely and let you know if I find anything relevant.

Comment: Ya Initially I also thought it will work. but it seemed not working. Thank you for helping me.

Comment: It seems like localStorage work ... what about using it and on close remove it from your browser ? You can use this page as exemple : http://mdn.github.io/web-storage-demo/

Comment: The problem with localstorage is that, it wont clear my auth token on closing the window. so when user opens a new window, it will be there and the system assumes that it is already logged in.

Comment: using javascript unload event to remove it ? Is it a valid option ? (I updated my answer)

Comment: While we closing the tab, the unload calls. If I remove it then, it will behave like sessionStorage, right?

Comment: To make sure you remove localStorage on unload, you should keep track of how many tabs are open (in a localStorage :D), and then only remove the auth on unload of the last tab :). It not last tab, you just decrease your localStorage counter of tabs ... should work, but seems a little bit ugly.

Comment: Ya. it will work, but ugly. Also if I just refresh the page, the local storage count will be increased.

Comment: I am giving a look about web socket and this kind of thing, I will let you know but I don't see any other alternative right now. Please just don't use flash ;), Ahah.

Comment: Please give a look at intercom.js, looks good to me. https://github.com/diy/intercom.js/